# Div inline alignment

Tags: html, css, position

I'm working on a simple image slider, which has a main container with a fixed width and then another div for controlling the movement of the slider.
It works fine but I would like to align the divs (with the `slide` class) beside each other, and the overflowing divs should be moved aside, and not "falling down".

I used the `overflow:hidden` property on the container and thought it should work and the overflowing divs should be on the sides but for some reason they keep falling down.
This is my pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOZVPL

They jQuery code isn't relevant for the current problem, so just ignore it.
I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap` on the element which has the `overflow: hidden` to prevent its contents from wrapping around to the next line.

The `overflow: hidden` would only suppress the display of the portions that are outside the container but it won't prevent the content from wrapping around.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = Math.floor($(".slide").length / 2);
  $('.slide').eq(index).addClass("focus");
  $("#right").click(function() {
    $('.slide').eq(index).removeClass("focus");
    index--;
    $('.slide').eq(index).addClass("focus");
    $("#sliding").css({
      left: $("#sliding").position().left - 144 + "px"
    });
  });
  $("#left").click(function() {

    $('.slide').eq(index).removeClass("focus");
    index++;
    $('.slide').eq(index).addClass("focus");
    $("#sliding").css({
      left: $("#sliding").position().left + 144 + "px"
    });

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slider {
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 1000px;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 160px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#sliding {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
.slide {
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/heDRFUE.jpg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(50%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
.focus {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(110%);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div id="sliding">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>

  </div>
</div>
</br>
<center>
  <button id="right">slide right</button>
</center>
<center>
  <button id="left">slide left</button>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you add the **width** an **float** attributes to your #sliding?

```
#sliding
{
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  transition:all 0.5s linear;
}
```

You maybe have to do some additional css changes here and there. But that brings the circles on one line.

The second option is to add **white-space: nowrap;** to your .slider class

```
.slider {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  direction: rtl;
  width:1000px;
  border:2px solid;
  height:160px;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here you can find more information about the white-space atttribute:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp